# Use names instead of colors in barplot legend

Tags: r, bar-chart

I have a table (named "c2") in RStudio with the following values:

```
c2 = c(AB=6821, SK=1896, MB=1182, NT=112, YT=88, NU=74, BC=10, ON=3, CA=1, NB=1, PL=1)
c2
#   AB   SK   MB   NT   YT   NU   BC   ON   CA   NB   PL 
# 6821 1896 1182  112   88   74   10    3    1    1    1
```

I wish to display a barplot, with the legend summarizing the counts.  My script is:

```
barplot(c2, main="Active Subscriber Counts", 
        xlab="PO", col = rainbow(20),
        ylim = c(0,7000), beside=TRUE, legend.text=c2)
```

Which gives me:

[image]

My problem is with the legend - instead of showing counts by color, I want it to display counts by "PO" ("AB", "SK", "MB", etc.). How might I amend my code to accomplish that?

Comment: This question is better suited for Stack Exchange.

Comment: Thank you. I have moved the question over to Stack Exchange, and will delete this.

Comment: B.Frost the correct action is not to repost, but to flag this post for migration (that in effect moves the question, while what you said did -- posting a new copy of it -- does not). Please keep that in mind.

Comment: This does belong on [SO], but we will migrate it for you.  You just need to wait a bit; you don't have to do anything.

Comment: @StatsStudent **1**. StackExchange is the name of the network, not of any individual site. Did you mean StackOverflow? $\:$ **2**. If you think a post is off-topic here and on topic elsewhere, *flag it for migration*

Comment: Thank you for moving the post.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a named vector, you can simply switch your `legend.text` argument from `c2` to `FALSE` and use the `legend()` function to get better control.  The following is a bit of a kluge, but may work well enough.  The problem is that the `pch` argument appears to require single character strings:

```
c2 <- c(AB=6821, SK=1896, MB=1182, NT=112, YT=88, NU=74, BC=10, ON=3, CA=1, NB=1, PL=1)

windows()
  barplot(c2, main="Active Subscriber Counts", 
          xlab="PO", col = rainbow(20),
          ylim = c(0,7000), beside=TRUE, legend.text=FALSE)
  legend("topright", legend=paste(names(c2), c2), pch="")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you - but what I need displayed is the PO (AB, SK, etc.) and the counts (like the example in OP). In this case the colors are not needed.  I want the legend to look like:

AB 6821
SK 1896
and so on...